# Centering labels using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I see a lot of posts on doing this with geom_text, but not how to do this with stat_summary. I try adding on to the "text" label, 
position = position_stack(0.5), but it just returns "cannot display this visual".

```
library(ggplot2)
```

## Aggregating Data

```
ag<- aggregate(dataset$Value, by = list(PvA=dataset$PvA, Area=dataset$Area, Unit=dataset$Unit), FUN=sum)
ag
```

## plotting

```
b<-ggplot(dataset, aes(x=PvA, y=Value, fill=Attribute)) + 
     stat_summary_bin(aes(fill=Attribute), fun.y = sum, geom="bar", position="stack", color="black")+
     stat_summary_bin(aes(label=..y..), fun.y=sum,  geom="text", color = "white", data=subset(dataset, Value >1))
b
```

[Dataset Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/am3w1ldhzsao3f2/Sample.txt?dl=0) (link to Dropbox download, txt file)

[image: Current Result]

Comment: Please post a sample of your data

Comment: There is a link above that contains the data. "Dataset Sample". Thanks!

Comment: It's preferable if you call `dput` on a representative sample of your dataset and post the result in the question. Makes it easier for folks to retrieve without having to download from a separate source

Comment: I'm building this inside PowerBi so I'm unsure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is actually more complicated than it seems like it needs to be. I'll illustrate with a subset of the `mpg` dataset, rather than downloading yours.

Instead of calculating simple summaries in `stat_summary_bin`, you can do them yourself before plotting (gives you control over what's going on), or you can have `geom_bar` do it. `geom_bar` is like `geom_col`, except it internally runs a `stat_count`. If you use the same stat in `geom_text`, you can access this calculated count to make labels. Then to center the labels, instead of the shorthand `position = "stack"`, you use `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)`.

Note that `stat(count)` is the replacement to `..count..`, which was briefly called `calc(count)`. I'm using the dev version from github; the CRAN version might still be `..count..` notation.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- mpg %>% filter(manufacturer %in% c("chevrolet", "dodge"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = manufacturer, fill = class)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = stat(count)), stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

The second way—my preference because it gives a little more control—is to calculate the counts and then pipe it into `ggplot`. Calling `count` gets you:

```r
df %>%
  count(manufacturer, class)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   manufacturer class       n
#>   <chr>        <chr>   <int>
#> 1 chevrolet    2seater     5
#> 2 chevrolet    midsize     5
#> 3 chevrolet    suv         9
#> 4 dodge        minivan    11
#> 5 dodge        pickup     19
#> 6 dodge        suv         7
```

Then you can pipe that into a simplified `ggplot` call. This gets the same plot, except that `count` will instead be labeled `n`.

```r
df %>%
  count(manufacturer, class) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = manufacturer, y = n, fill = class)) +
    geom_col(position = "stack") +
    geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: I agree with your "aggregating outside of ggplot2" advice.  But did you find a way to use `position_stack()` with a summary function (I think `stat(y)`) instead of counts (`stat(count)`)?  I haven't figured it out.

Comment: I'm very new to R. I do know i HAVE to have a summary for the label, because if I dont, it gives me a label for every row within the stack.  This is my final product I want to achieve: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpebuaym1o2hyff/RscriptHelp.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: @aosmith Hmmm, no. When I try `position = "stack"` inside `stat_summary`, I get `Error in if (any(negative)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Not the same error as the OP reported but still no fun

Comment: @RebeccaS That might actually be a good reason to do your summary before plotting. In `dplyr` it would be `count(*)` like in my second method, where `*` is whatever groups you need to aggregate over

Comment: I feel I'm getting closer. Even after summing up my values before plotting, I now get multiple values per bar. ggplot(dataset, aes(x=PvA, y=Value, fill=Attribute, label = Area_Totals)) + 
     geom_bar(position = "stack", stat="identity") + 
     geom_text(stat="identity", position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))+
coord_flip() +
facet_grid (Area ~.)    Now resulting in [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbx8vpcj41piadd/RscriptHelp_2.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: @RebeccaS Go ahead and add your new attempts to the question so it's easier for people to see. Maybe try `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`, since you're giving it `stat = "identity"` anyway