# Error when setting position in stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar plot with labels on each of the bars. The following code works:

```
library(ggplot2)

spending <- data.frame(
  year = factor(c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)),
  amount = c(13, 82, 58, 93, 72, 11, 9, 44),
  category = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b")
)

ggplot(spending, aes(x=year, y=amount, fill=category)) +
stat_summary(fun="sum", geom="bar", position="stack") +
stat_summary(fun="sum", geom="text", aes(label=stat(y)))
```

...but the labels are in the wrong position. If I add `position="stack"` or `position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)` to the last line, to try to align them with the bars, I get:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
Execution halted
```

Why does stacking throw that strange error while `position="dodge"` works just fine? What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like it should works since ggplot 3.3.0 as a bug related to combining stat_summary + text + stack was fixed then (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2709) but it still does not work for me know.

Comment: I opened a follow up issue here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4367

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach to achieving what I think you are after, but I had to take a different approach to the `stat_summary` functions.

I'm not sure if it is easy to do what you want with `stat_summary` see this post: [Centering labels using stat_summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969378/centering-labels-using-stat-summary)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)


spending <- 
  spending %>% 
  group_by(year, category) %>% 
  summarise(amount = sum(amount))



ggplot(spending, aes(x=year, y=amount, fill=category)) +
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = amount), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>